# What is the grammar in Кофе с собой?

Tags: грамматика, phrase

These days one sees often the phrase *Кофе с собой* at some coffee shops. It seems to be equivalent to *Coffee to go*, but how does this contruction work? Does *собой* refer to the coffee or the one who takes it along?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Кофе с собой?

is a short form of the question

> Вы хотите взять кофе с собой?

where собой is a reflexive pronoun себя in the instrumental case corresponding to the personal pronoun "you". Another variant is

> Вам сделать кофе с собой?(собой refers to you).

Comment: There is usually no question mark in such a sentence (i.e. when it is written on a window of a coffee shop). You're right  about a short form if _Кофе с собой?_ is asked by a barista, but the OP asked about phrase one can see, not hear :) Therefore @Alex_ander 's answer seems more correct to me.

Comment: Either spoken or written it means the same. The OP asks about grammar not the meaning, btw.Anyway, thanks for your attention Everyone is welcome to have  their own opinion.

Comment: Following your logic, this phrase is a direct suggestion. I personally tend to think that it just describes some type of dish one can order in that cafe. So it's more likely a short form of _Вы **можете** взять кофе с собой (в нашем кафе)._ Please don't feel insulted, it's just my reasoning.

Answer (score 7):

It means the visitors can take their (likely, plastic) cup of coffee (**with them**; literally '*with themselves*') and go.

Answer (score 4):

> Взять с собой = take with oneself

Answer (score 0):

the phrase sounds counter-intuitive to me (i'm not disputing the fact of it being used somewhere)

the meaning i read into it is `one must BRING coffee with them` NOT `TAKE AWAY with them`

because in Russian so far as my life experience tells me `с собой` usually `приносят` and not `забирают/уносят`, speaking usage wise

the meaning of `taking away` in the name of a service would be best conveyed with `кофе навынос`

Comment: Это выражение используется во всех едальнях (кафе, ресторанах и т.д.). А если говорить о том что именно делают с тем, что "с собой", то тогда уж "берут" (например "я взял с собой зонтик, солнечные очки и перекус"). "Кофе на вынос" тоже годится, но я очень давно не слышала чтобы кто-нибудь так говорил.

Comment: Да, кофе "на вынос" - излишне формально, так иногда пишут в прейскурантах, но почти не говорят. "С собой" именно "берут", причем "берут с собой" _всегда_ "**уходя**". Слова  _принести_ (to bring) или _унести_ (to take away) не нуждаются в дополнении "с собой": они его косвенно содержат (как напр. в выражении "приносить и распивать спиртные напитки запрещается").